# Setting / accessing the Application.CutCopyMode property via UI

Tags: ms-word

We are facing an error of "This method or property is not available because the clipboard is empty or not valid" in one of our Lotus Notes applications. The code basically opens a document, selects all the text, copies it and then pastes it in MS Word document. It does this continuously for a bunch of documents. I found this [link](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1637602) which basically suggests adding `Application.CutCopyMode = False` to the code to resolve the issue.

I need to know can this property be accessed and set via UI for MS Word?

Answer (score 0):

In the example you reference, that Keyword is actually part of the Excel object model, not the Word object model. So you are unlikely to find it in Word's UI. Perhaps you are doing something with Excel as well, or perhaps it is a keyword in the relevant Lotus object model as well?

[
The OP mentioned a link,  http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Word/microsoft.public.word.vba.general/2007-06/msg00446.html
that suggested changing variables names, but that that did not work.

The linked article also suggests "sleeping for a few milliseconds between copying and pasting"
]

Comment: Oh... yes the link points for Excel. I also checked the Word API and it does not offer `Application.CutCopyMode = False`. I found this link http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Word/microsoft.public.word.vba.general/2007-06/msg00446.html which basically suggests changing variables names, but that to hasn't worked.